# Swift - WKWebView - No se levanta prompt de autenticación

Tags: ios, swift

En una aplicación iOS estoy mostrando en un WKWebView (con NavigatorController) una aplicación web, esta aplicación web tiene un iframe a una app que levanta el típico Auth Prompt para authenticarse pero este prompt no se está viendo en la aplicación iOS, según lo que he buscado, he probado lo siguiente:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

 

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler()

        }))

 

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

 

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

 

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler(true)

        }))

 

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler(false)

        }))

 

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

 

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

 

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in

            textField.text = defaultText

        }

 

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {

                completionHandler(text)

            } else {

                completionHandler(defaultText)

            }

        }))

 

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler(nil)

        }))

 

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge:

    URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        let user = "*****"

        let password = "*****"

        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)

        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, credential)

 

    }
```

help

Comment: Si agregaste el delegate `self.webView?.uiDelegate = self`?

Comment: si lo tengo agregado

Comment: Con esta línea `self.webView.navigationDelegate = self` debería entrar en la función `didReceive`.